# Android layout background gradient without xml

Tags: java, android, layout, background, gradient

How can I set a layout background to a two color gradient using java? All the solutions I find online show how to do it with XML only.

For example if I wanted to set the MenuLayout background to a gradient instead of red.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout HomeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    HomeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ebebeb"));

    LinearLayout MenuLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    MenuLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    HomeLayout.addView(MenuLayout);

    setContentView(HomeLayout);
}
```

Comment: You would need to create [a `GradientDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) yourself in Java code.

Comment: Could you please refer me to a good example of such implementation?

Comment: I have never done this personally. Using your favorite search engine, search for `android "new GradientDrawable"` or something.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

Comment: thank you I found a few examples with your help and did it! :)

Comment: Please post what you did so that other can get help, thanks